# Node js is still listening to the port after ctrl+z

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I am trying to learn some features of node on ubuntu and after I press ctrl+z on my console to stop the server I had (in order to restart server for recognizing my changes on the code), the node still listens to the port (in this case 3000 ).

Then, everytime I have to find the pid by typing

```
lsof -i tcp:3000
```

and kill it manually by typing

```
sudo kill -9 pid_number_I_got
```

I just wonder why it still listens to it and I want not to have to do this thing everytime. Any help ?

---

The code

```
var http = require("http");

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.url , req.method);
    res.end("hello \n");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

The answer is correct. Type ctrl+c , it works. I was typing ctrl+x instead.

Comment: isn't the command to kill process ctrl+c not ctrl+z

Answer (score 27, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> moves a running application to the background; you can run the `fg` command to resume it. To stop the server, you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: @FurkanO Do you know why not? Is the application configured to capture that signal and prevent the app from stopping?

Comment: @FurkanO Ah, yeah that's pretty basic. Ctrl+C is the way to stop it. Is something on your machine or terminal configured to not send the `SIGINT` signal?

Comment: @FurkanO Try running the command `yes`. It outputs the character "y" over and over again until you stop it. Ctrl+C should be able to stop it. (If it doesn't work, `ps | grep yes` to find the process and kill it like the other process.)

Comment: @FurkanO How are you starting the process? (Feel free to edit the question)

Comment: Hahaha, well I'm glad you got it figured out :)

Comment: can we disable Ctrl + z function in repl ( repl module )?

Answer (score 4):

My favourite to fix all things ghost listening ports is:

```
killall node
```

But even then, very rarely, I just have to reboot.

If you want a proper change watcher though, use [forever](/questions/tagged/forever). It'll watch the file system and rerun the app every time a change is detected.

If you use Sublime Text, you can even set up a build system that will run forever directly out of Sublime.